# Are method swizzling and isa swizzling the same thing?

Tags: objective-c, swizzling, method-swizzling, isa-swizzling

Are method swizzling and isa swizzling the same thing? If not, then what is isa swizzling?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## Method Swizzling

Method swizzling **exchanges the implementation of two methods of a class at runtime**. This will affect every instance, which was or will be created, of the modified class.

Example:
Let's assume you have written a category for NSString:

```
@interface NSString (Swizzling)
@end
@implementation NSString (Swizzling)
- (NSString *)swizzled_uppercaseString {
    //when the method is swizzled, the original method will be called 
    //with swizzled_uppercaseString (so this will not create a stack overflow).
    NSString *result = [self swizzled_uppercaseString];
    // our custom code
    result = [result stringByAppendingString:@" (swizzled)"];
    return result;
}
@end
```

You can then exchange the implementation of the `uppercaseString`-method with the `swizzled_uppercaseString`-method, so the implementation of the `swizzled_uppercaseString` method is executed, when `uppercaseString` is called. (And the original implementation of `uppercaseString` is executed, when calling `swizzled_uppercaseString`):

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

NSString *sample = @"abc";

// original method is called:
NSLog([sample uppercaseString]); 

//Obtaining original and swizzled method:
original = class_getInstanceMethod([NSString class], @selector(uppercaseString));
swizzled = class_getInstanceMethod([NSString class], @selector(swizzled_uppercaseString));

//Exchange implementations here:
method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzled);

// swizzled method is called:
NSLog([sample uppercaseString]); //prints "ABC (swizzled)"
```

---

## ISA Swizzling

ISA swizzling modifies a property on a single object, the ISA ('is a') property, which describes the class of an object, so you can **exchange the type of a given single object with another type at runtime.**

Example:
Let's assume you have this class structure:

```
@interface Sample : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSString *sampleStringToLoad;
@end
@implementation Sample
@synthesize sampleStringToLoad;
@end

@interface SampleWithStringLoader :NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSString *sampleStringToLoad;
-(void)loadString;
@end
@implementation SampleWithStringLoader
@synthesize sampleStringToLoad;
-(void)loadString {
self.sampleStringToLoad = @"abc";
}
@end
```

You can then set the class to `SampleWithStringLoader`, so the `sampleStringToLoad`-method becomes available:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

Sample *sample = [Sample new];
// switch isa to new class:
object_setClass(sample, [SampleWithStringLoader class]);

// invoke method that is only in SampleWithStringLoader: 
[sample performSelector:@selector(loadString)]; 

// switch isa back to original class:
object_setClass(sample,[Sample class]); 

// Prints 'abc':
NSLog(sample.sampleStringToLoad);
```